# How do I enable NumLock at login?

Tags: settings, keyboard

I'd like to be able to use my number pad immediately after login without having to manually activate it by pressing <kbd>NumLock</kbd>.

Answer (score 12):

Open *System Settings* and click *Keyboard*:

[image]

Switch to the tab *Options*

[image]

Now choose *Miscellaneous compatibility options* on the left side, and check *Default numeric keypad keys* on the right side.

That's all!

This setting takes effect after Login and has no effect at the login screen or consoles.

If it doesn't work for you, try checking *Numeric keypad keys always enter digits*

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was in there! Anyway, your solution actually **doesn't work** for me. What seems to do the trick is in fact the first option in your screenshot ("Numeric keypad keys always enter digits"). Moreover, it takes effect immediately with no need to log out. Any idea why?

Comment: @saintjules 5 have no idea, why it doesn't work for you, but I'll the other option as alternative to my answer. It worked for my years ago, when I had a desktop computer...

Comment: I have a Lenovo laptop. Maybe it depends on the hardware, then. Let's see if anyone can shed some light on this.

Comment: I don't have any option tab.

Comment: @Arif me too, but in the first screenshot he has Tweaks installed, so maybe that's why

Answer (score 8):

Edit `/etc/lightdm/pantheon-greeter.conf` (in newer versions `io.elementary.greeter.conf`) with you favorite editor and remove the `#` on the line `activate-numlock=true`.

Comment: This doesn't work after the [August greeter update](https://blog.elementary.io/say-hello-to-the-new-greeter/). See [this issue](https://github.com/elementary/greeter/issues/337) on GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative option assuming you are using the text editor that came with Elementary OS. In the terminal:

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/40-pantheon-greeter.conf
```

When it opens up in scratch, add the following line to the end of the file:

```
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

Save the file and restart the computer. At the login screen, the numlock key should be turned on. Also, when you log out, it will also remain on at the login screen.

Comment: It might be worth nothing that `gedit` will not work on a clean install since that app is not shipped with elementary OS and you should use `-H` if you run graphical apps as root.

Answer (score 3):

This may not apply to you, but it will apply to others out there. Some BIOS's have an option to turn it on automatically.

For example, the ASUS ROG G20AJ Gaming PC's BIOS has this option.

Answer (score 1):

There are several changes made on the system, so on Elementary 5 Juno you need a bit different approach.

- Install gedit from AppCenter
- Open Terminal and paste code below

> gedit admin:///etc/lightdm/io.elementary.greeter.conf

gedit admin:// - opens and edits file as root, just add path to your file.

add **activate-numlock=true** if missing or **remove #** if #activate-numlock=true exits.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera :

- Open terminal

  sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/40-io.elementary.greeter.conf
- add this line at the end of the file :

  greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
- save (ctrl+o)
- quit nano (ctrl+x) and close the terminal
- restart your computer and it supposed to work