# getting NumLock to be on by default on start login screen (SOLVED)

Tags: release-loki, greeter

I installed elementaryos-0.4.1-stable.20170517.iso several times on my intel/nvidia laptop the first time i did the install i could enter numbers on my numpad. After doing a clean install, now on boot numlock is OFF by default no matter what state i leave it in before i shut it down. I tried adding

```
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

after

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

which led to not being able to boot so then using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> at boot and recovery mode removed it back to normal, i saw older posts on this forum that you could just open `settings->keyboard` but i believe that was relevant for a version 2 yrs ago.

I am up to date to latest version as of this post

Comment: It's very weird, that command must fix that, can you please output your /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf ?

Comment: the document appears to be blank, maybe that is how it was done in the older versions

Comment: So i figured it out

    sudo nano /etc/lightdm/pantheon-greeter.conf

then add

   activate-numlock=true

that fixed it

Comment: I forgot that elementary uses his own greeter,  glad to see that you fixed your problem

Comment: see my comment in another question. https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/12745/8404

Answer (score 0):

Adding/editing `greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on` in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` works for me on `elementary OS 5.1.6 Hera` very well. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM#NumLock_on_by_default confirms this solution. Just for the case someone else is looking for a way to enable NumLock in login screen on default.

Answer (score 0):

On Elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera, there is a file `/etc/lightdm/io.elementary.greeter.conf` that has the line `#activate-numlock=true`. Simply uncomment the line (remove the hash symbol from the start of the line) and the numlock should now be enabled on the login screen. It stays enabled after login as well.