# Right Numeric keypad stopped working on Elementary OS

Tags: keyboard

I am pretty new to the Linux Environment and the first Distro I wanted to try was the Elementary OS, so far it's been amazing experience. So it's been a week I am using Elementary OS and all of a sudden my numeric keypad stopped working (Right Numeric keypad) however the numeric keypad that is below the function keys is working just fine(Relief). Interestingly, the right number keypad stopped working after I log in to my system. My password contains some numbers and it does work in the password field, but once logged in it stopped working. Anyone has any solution to this problem? I really want to explore more of this however this lil problems limit me. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I think this is a known issue. See if this solution works:
https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/373/how-do-i-enable-numlock-at-login/375#375

Comment: Thanks but it did not work, mine doesn't show the "option" tab. :(