# Numpad don't work

Tags: keyboard

recently I have installed elementary OS but my numpad don't work. I have tried installing several applications, but there wasn't much difference. Can someone help me how to turn it on?

Comment: See this: [enter link description here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/373/how-do-i-enable-numlock-at-login)

Answer (score -1):

There are answers in the Internet. All you need to do is to look for in Google. You did not even try. I gave you a link above in the comment. I would like to ask you to try to search in Google for such a trivial issues.