# How do i enable the numeric keys (on the right side of my keyboard) under elementary OS 5.1.3

Tags: release-hera, keyboard

The numeric keypad on the right side of my keyboard does not appear to work under elementary OS 5.1.3.  I checked the keyboard settings and there does not appear to be any settings related to this.  I searched this site and it appears that in an earlier version of elementary, there was a keyboard setting (described here: [How do I enable NumLock at login?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/373/how-do-i-enable-numlock-at-login/375#375)) but that setting no longer appears in the keyboard setting.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid me.  The num lock key wasn't set.