# How to force lock num to be always on

Tags: keyboard

In previous versions of elementray OS you could make "numeric pad keys always enter digits". See [this answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/373/how-do-i-enable-numlock-at-login) and screenshot below:

[image]

This setting is also available on Ubuntu (see [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/71630/numlock-is-completely-useless-and-i-want-to-disable-it-completely-on-linux)).

However, in elementary OS 5, this setting is not available:

[image]

I don't know if I accidentally press the numlock key or it's some random bug, but I'm constantly trying to enter a number with the numeric pad and end up moving to the top of the document, enabling "insert" or deleting something. Is there any way of making sure that the numeric keyboard lives to its name and only enters numbers in elementary OS 5 (and hopefully the upcoming 6)?

Quoting [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/71630/numlock-is-completely-useless-and-i-want-to-disable-it-completely-on-linux):

> Please note that I do not want to know how to turn Num Lock on at startup, I do not want to know how to tear the key off, I want to disable it so that it stays on all the time and can't be turned off by mistake. Any idea how to do that?

EDIT: Found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509784/numeric-pad-always-enter-digits), that proposes this command:

```
setxkbmap -option numpad:mac
```

It works perfectly but it turns off seemingly randomly or after some time. To make it permanent, I need to edit 10-keyboard.conf (see [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1222529#p1222529)), but I don't know where to find it. For now I added that command to the startup commands and seems to work.

Comment: What happens if you install 'numlockx' and reboot? Try `sudo apt install numlockx`, press enter, authenticate, let it do its thing, and then reboot. It may be necessary to add it to autostart somewhere and I don't have my eOS VM handy to check that.

Comment: "numlockx is already the newest version (1.2-7ubuntu1)." I guess I had in installed already, so no change there. See the edit for further information on a possible solution. I add that running numlockx seems to prevent that solution from working. :\

Comment: Add `/usr/bin/numlockx` to your startup sequence. Open the menu, type start, it's under applications > startup (or similar - my VM still isn't handy) and add the above as a startup item. Reboot and see if it takes.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that command did the trick?

Comment: No, it doesn't work. :( The Numlock key still toggles the numeric keyboard. My workaround right now is to use Keymapper to map numlock to escape. Not the most elegant solution.

Comment: That's crazy. It should *definitely* be working. As for the 10-keyboard.conf file, that's actually not a file you find - it's a file you create. I dug out [this link](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout_switching) for you to explore. Scroll down or do a CTRL + F for '10-keyboard.conf' and you'll find directions. Yes, it says Gentoo, but it's something you should be able to use in any distro that uses/supports x11 - which is pretty much all of them, including eOS.